# Dpll, SAT (satisfability) problem, Need DPLL Function or Procedure?

Tags: matlab, satisfiability

here is my problem, I stucked in Matlab with SAT Problem (Satisfability)

Actually I need a function called DPLL, I saw it somewhere here but it's in java, can anyone help me please?

Comment: To the question "can anyone help me please?", the answer is probably "yes". So, *what's the **real** question?*

Comment: You misunderstood me. We *do* want to help. You have not given enough information for us to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MATLAB has an embedded JVM, and makes it easy to call Java classes from inside MATLAB.

This is well explained in [the documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/using-java-libraries-in-matlab.html)